# Elements Below Ground Energy State

Tags: energy, plasma-physics, hydrogen, ground-state

I have been hearing things about people getting elements like hydrogen below the ground energy state. I don't understand how that is even possible. The more interesting thing is how this actually produced power in the form of plasma. I want to know if this is real and if it is, how does it work?

Comment: Where have you been hearing things - can you point to a source?

Comment: @JonCuster This question sounds like it might have originated from some version of the "hydrino" model, which has been promoted by Randell Mills and others at [Brilliant Light Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brilliant_Light_Power).  If so, the idea has been [thoroughly debunked](https://www.esa.int/gsp/ACT/doc/PHY/ACT-RPR-PHY-Rathke-hydrino.pdf) by mainstream scientists.

Comment: @Thorondor - I agree the question sounds very non-mainstream, but was giving some benefit of the doubt. Hardly the first...